# Check if RSS feed is associated with URL using PHP

Tags: php, rss

Is it possible to find out from an URL if there is a RSS feed associated.

eg.  I have the url www.MyDomainName.com.  Now is it possible to detect programmatically if there an RSS associated with the URL using PHP apart from PARSING.

Comment: How do you mean "apart from PARSING"?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, it is no possible to tell just from the URL, however you should be able to tell if you load the URL's HTML code, for example using something like PHP's file_get_contents, or CURL.

Normally a website with an RSS feed available will make a declaration to the feed within the page's HTML code, here is an example of what you would normally see:

```
<link rel="alternate" type="application/rss+xml" title="Example" href="http://www.example.com/feed/" />
```

Therefore I would suggest looking for a HTML "link" tag, with the type set to "application/rss+xml", obviously the 'herf' will then provide you with the URL for the RSS feed.

Answer (score 1):

You cant tell for sure, but most people use a `link` tag when there is one.

Use [file_get_contents](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php) to get the file in text format, and then search for

```
type="application/rss+xml"
```